# How to list all currently online admin users?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, admin-user

In Magento I have created multiple admins with different roles. How do I get the list of online admin users. Similar to the online customers list?

I have used

```
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')
```

but this is providing only the current user's details.

Is there any build in functions. If not, how to create similar thing?

Comment: In table admin_user there is the column logdate (User Last Login Time)

Comment: @helcode but with that how can we get the real time list of online admins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should know that it is not possible to find out which users are currently on the site, at least not with reasonable effort. The "online customers" list shows all customers that have been active within the last X minutes.

Since there is no visitor log for admins, you don't have a "last active" time, as it is used for the "online customers" list. You can count all admins that have logged in within the last hour as "online", or implement an admin visitor log on your own, mimicking the customer visitor log.