# How to check if user is logged into the admin

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, user-roles, user

I'm trying to create a script then trigger it from time to time to check "who" is logged in in admin (users), so I created this:

```
$adminUser = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$users = $adminUser->getCollection()->load();
echo '<pre>';
foreach($users as $user){
$name = $user->getUsername();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>$name));
    if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        echo $name.' is logged in<br/>';
    }else{
        echo " go away bad boy<br/>";
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
```

?>

Simplified code .... still no positive results ....

Comment: You want to get _the_ backend user that is currently logged in or _all_ backend users that are currently logged in? All logged in, right?

Comment: Hello Christoph, yes, I would like to check if any of the users is logged in into backend. As you can see I'm getting whole collection of users then looping trough but ..... it does not work.

Comment: Actually I don't think this is possible (though I don't want to discourage you quite yet). However, one of the main issues could be the question of how Magento should figure out whether a user is actually still logged in if s/he isn't doing anything in the backend? I mean to say, what if for example the backend user clears its cookies... Magento would never know (at least not until the user logs in again which should give you a time stamp if I'm not wrong). That being said I believe there are just two options: comparing login time stamps and just **assume** a user is logged in, or ...

Comment: setting up an observer quite at the base that is populating a "I'm still here" time stamp on every action's call. Though I might be mistaken and in that case my apologies already now, in case this was complete nonsense ;)

Comment: Have you got any example of how  or what function/class/method should I observe to achieve it ?

Comment: `controller_action_predispatch` that would be like the most classy event to watch out for (but  be aware it is used in frontend and backend)

Comment: but i can filter and get only data from backend right ?
The other solution I'm considering is just a simple ajax sending signals every few minutes if user is logged in into the table updating status "live/dead" .....

Comment: Ok, so based on above assumption I did a quick crosscheck - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83540/how-to-list-all-currently-online-admin-users - @FabianSchmengler seems to be on the same page about the possibility in this topic. I think I would go for an additional column in the user table (in case there is nothing like a current time stamp already) and track the users action in this way. Using that information you can at least know when the last action by an user happened - which than could be combined with the session lifetime for a rough idea about whether a user can be loggedin

Comment: yes, you should be able to do something like this in the observer: `Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->getUser()` which gives you the current user. You should make sure however, that all your logging is happening if it is an adminhtml interaction and only then check for the current user. About your other approach, yes that can work out as well, you'd just need to figure first of all, what you actually want to know and track from your admins ([possibly] active session/login, actual interaction, idle state, ...)

Comment: It seems like you are one of those people who always have something to say to annoy other people. What is wrong with you "sv3n" .... nobody likes you ??
I know there possibly someone already asked similar question but ... who care ? 
Similar does not mean the same and maybe there was no answer ?

Comment: Yes I've read Mr Shmengler's answer but it does not say are we talking about front end or backend so I know it is not possible just like that. I was interested only about backend to find out who is currently working/is logged in!
So please ..... leave.

Comment: I've flagged this a "possible" duplicate, because it's seems to be exactly the same question - you want to know who's currently logged in in backend, right? Fabian gave an answer there, that fits to it.

Comment: Please check this ... https://github.com/firegento/firegento-adminmonitoring ... guess you'll find some code that could help you.

Answer (score 3):

Use below code:

```
//get the admin session
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'adminhtml'));

//verify if the user is logged in to the backend
if(Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isLoggedIn()){
  //do stuff
}
else
{
  echo "go away bad boy";
}
```

Comment: Thanx but you just gave me the same code as I already have and it does actually the same ..... don't work. 
I have a whole collection loaded, then looping trough to check if user/users are logged in but as a result I'm getting 'user not logged in' even if I'm ;(

Comment: Slightly modified/simplified code but it still does not work